# Loading pool layer of simple transformer

Tags: python, nlp, pytorch, bert-language-model, simpletransformers

I have a fine tuned simple transformer representation model. Now I want to save the weights of only the pool layer in pickle format and put it in the pool layer of another custom auto encoder that I am designing .How can i do this using pytorch and python ?

Answer (score 0):

There is an object called `state_dict` alongside each PyTorch module which allows mapping any parameter to its correspondent tensor variable (more on this [here](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/recipes/recipes/what_is_state_dict.html)). Using this Utility you can save and load parameters easily but keep in mind you must be sure about what you want to do beforehand both semantically (from the machine learning point of view) and syntactically (shape compatibility and ...)! Below implementation would replace any parameter with word `pooling` in its name, with the corresponding variable from the model we saved before.

```
finetuned_model = BertLMHeadModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-cased')
torch.save(finetuned_model.state_dict(), "finetuned_model.pth")
finetuned_model_state_dict = torch.load("finetuned_model.pth")
new_model = BertLMHeadModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-cased')
new_model_state_dict = new_model.state_dict()
for key, value in new_model_state_dict.items():
  if key.find('pooling')!=-1:
    new_model_state_dict.update({key: value})
```

Comment: @Parmida Granfar did the answer provide any help?